# How to show line endings and control characters in a file on Windows Server?

Tags: windows, files

I am having some issues with My Windows Servers where I need to add --server to Puppet runs or it won't work, despite having the correct server set in the config file.  I am wondering if there is a Linux line ending instead of a Windows crlf.  Whats an easy way to check this from the Windows box?

Comment: Open file on windows using notepad++ which can show all hidden chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use a quick VBS hack:

```
'
' Save this as "myscript.vbs" and then execute from command line like:
'   cscript.exe myscript.vbs "<file to check>"
'
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Dim objArgs
Dim objFSO
Dim objTextFile
Dim strFileContentsIn
Dim strFileContentsOut
Dim intCharIndex
strFileContentsOut = ""
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "ERROR : Bad args."
    Err.Clear
Else
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "ERROR : Failed to create File System Object."
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( objArgs.Item(0) )
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            WScript.Echo "ERROR : Failed to open file."
            Err.Clear
        Else
            strFileContentsIn = objTextFile.ReadAll
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                WScript.Echo "ERROR : Failed to read file."
                Err.Clear
            Else
                For intCharIndex = 1 To Len( strFileContentsIn )
                    If ( Asc(Mid( strFileContentsIn, intCharIndex, 1 )) = 10 ) Then
                        strFileContentsOut = strFileContentsOut & "\n" & VbCrLf
                    ElseIf ( Asc(Mid( strFileContentsIn, intCharIndex, 1 )) = 13 ) Then
                        strFileContentsOut = strFileContentsOut & "\r"
                    Else
                        strFileContentsOut = strFileContentsOut & Mid( strFileContentsIn, intCharIndex, 1 )
                    End If
                Next
                WScript.Echo strFileContentsOut
            End If
            objTextFile.Close
            Set objTextFile = Nothing
        End If
        Set objFSO = Nothing
    End If
End If
```

---

Alternative, shorter PowerShell version.  Still not a native command :\

```
(([IO.File]::ReadAllText( "<filepath>" ) -replace "`r", "\r") -replace "`n", "\n")
```

Comment: "Quick"? hack??  Haha!  Looks like a nice script, but considering the task, I wouldn't call it quick when compared to Linux, where I would vim +:'set list' filename  Thanks, at least it doesn't require 3rd party tools.

Comment: Granted!  See update for shorter PowerShell option.